# Animate div from center to the right (css or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to animate this centered (with margin auto) div to the right:

```css
.button  {
 border-radius:10px;
 padding:10px 5px;
 transition:background .4s;
 box-shadow:inset 0 -2px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 cursor:pointer;
}
.button:active {
 box-shadow:0 0 0 0;
 position:relative;
 top:2px;
}


#submit {
 font-size:2.5rem;
 color:#fcfcfd;
 background: rgba(203, 78, 78, 0.8);
 width:200px;
 margin:80px auto 0 auto;
 transition: margin .5s ease-in-out;
}
#submit:hover {
 background: rgba(203, 78, 78, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="submit" class="button">Button that doesn't do anything.</div>
```

But here's the problem: I cannot set a percentage width because if I do that, resizing the browser, the text will run out from the button background and I don't want to set any media query for the text.
I tried also with css transition, but it can't do that with margin auto. I also tried with jquery doing it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
         $( "#submit" ).animate({
          marginRight: "10%"
           }, 500);
      });
```

And it works but it acts weird because it resets the margin left to 0 and after it goes to the right.
What can I do?

Comment: Is requirement to animate `div` to right , remaining in  viewport ? Not certain what exact expected result is ?

Comment: If the problem is using % widths add `overflow:hidden;` to #submit

Comment: Do you want the div to go right after clicking on "go" ? Im confused about your needs

Comment: No I do not need the div to go right clicking on "Go"... I'm not a noob. doesn't matter what fires the animation, it's like $(document).ready( animate etc.);

Overflow hidden is a good trick but it hides the text when the window's resized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpreted your question correctly, this should work:

Try adding `top:80px;` to the CSS for `#submit` and substituting the `left` property for the `margin` property for the `.animate()` function.

```js
$(function() {
  var button = $("#submit");
  button.css(
    "left", "calc(" + ((window.innerWidth / 2) - button.width() / 2) + "px)"
  )
  .animate({
    left: ((window.innerWidth) - (button.width() + 50))
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
.button {
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  transition: background .4s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 2px;
}
#submit {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  color: #fcfcfd;
  background: rgba(203, 78, 78, 0.8);
  width: 200px;
  top: 80px;
  /* margin: 80px auto 0 auto; */
  transition: left .5s ease-in-out; 
}
#submit:hover {
  background: rgba(203, 78, 78, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="submit" class="button">Button that doesn't do anything.</div>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jd8eea3e/2/embedded/result/

Comment: Thank you very much first of all. As I said in a comment before, I don't want to fire the event after a click. I'm not a noob, I just don't know how to speak english well :)
What I need is just to animate the movement to the right of that div when the document is ready (for example).

Answer (score 0):

I saw the solution of @guest271314 and his javascript seemed unnecessary to me, but he made me know the calc css function and so I solved it in this way:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $( "#submit" ).animate({
        left: "70%"
 }, 500);
}
```

```css
.button  {
 border-radius:10px;
 padding:10px 5px;
 transition:background .4s;
 box-shadow:inset 0 -2px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
 cursor:pointer;
}
.button:active {
 box-shadow:0 0 0 0;
 position:relative;
 top:2px;
}


#submit {
 font-size:2.5rem;
 color:#fcfcfd;
 background: rgba(203, 78, 78, 0.8);
 width:200px;
 margin-top:80px;
 position:relative;
 left:calc(50% - 100px); /* 50% minus half of the width in pixel */
 transition: margin .5s ease-in-out;
}
#submit:hover {
 background: rgba(203, 78, 78, 0.5);
}
```

```html
 <div id="submit" class="button">Do nothing!</div>
```